# How to get the virtual key codes from string in delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am using the following code to execute key stroke events:

```
keybd_event(VK_Tab, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
keybd_event(VK_Tab, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

I have a string. Lets say "Hello World 123".

I need to type the string in a labeled edit using virtual key strokes. The code below works fine. But only with numbers. Not letters or special caracters.

The string typed would also have to be case sensative.

```
Var
Key:Char;

for I := 1 to Length(Labelededit1.Text) do
 Begin
  Key:=Labelededit1.Text[I];
  keybd_event(Ord(Key), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
  keybd_event(Ord(Key), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  sleep(100);
 End;
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question that you asked, you can use [`VkKeyScan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646329.aspx) or [`VkKeyScanEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646332.aspx) to translate characters to virtual key codes. As well as the key code, these functions return the shift state required to type the character.

If you are to do this then you do need to stop using `keybd_event` and switch to `SendInput`, for the reasons stated in the documentations to those functions. If you use `keybd_event` then you might find your fake input messages being interleaved with real ones. Or other people's fake input messages. The whole raison d'être of `SendInput` is to avoid that.

The other issue that you will face is that your approach can only work for characters that can be typed on the active keyboard layout. For instance, your approach will not let you type *raison d'être* on my keyboard because I've got a UK keyboard. Trying to type characters that are not found on your keyboard using your approach is going to be quite a struggle.

So, I think that the best advice for you is to go back to the drawing board and look for other solutions to your problem. It seems likely that [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) will be a better fit to your problem.

Comment: [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). Without a hyperlink people will not even consider it a solution.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. In my experience, even with a hundred links, the majority of people seem to reject it and continue attempting to fake input!  ;-)